# Why can I not create / access futures in callables submitted to ProcessPoolExecutor?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multithreading, python-multiprocessing, concurrent.futures

Why does this code work with threads but not processes?

```
import concurrent.futures as f
import time
def wait_on_b():
    time.sleep(2)
    print(b.result())
    return 5

def wait_5():
    time.sleep(2)
    return 6

THREADS = False
if THREADS:
    executor = f.ThreadPoolExecutor()
else:
    executor = f.ProcessPoolExecutor()
a = executor.submit(wait_on_b)
b = executor.submit(wait_5)
print(a.result()) # works fine if THREADS, BrokenProcessPool otherwise
```

The [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#processpoolexecutor) do warn:

> Calling Executor or Future methods from a callable submitted to a ProcessPoolExecutor will result in deadlock.

The docs don't seem to mention raising an exception, so does it mean `ProcessPoolExecutor` somehow discovered the deadlock and resolved it by killing both processes?

More importantly, why is this deadlock unavoidable with processes (and avoidable with threads), and what is the workaround if I want to use multiple processes with futures, without being so restricted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using threads the **memory is shared** between all threads and that's why *wait_on_b* can access *b*.

Using processes, A **new memory space** is created for each process (copy of the old one *in fork mode*) so You will get a copy of *b* with a broken PIPE since it is not the **real** *b* (just a copy)

BTW: on windows there is **no fork**, so *b* (the memory is totally new) does not exists and you'll get a

```
concurrent.futures.process._RemoteTraceback: 
    """
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\concurrent\futures\process.py", line 175, in _process_worker
        r = call_item.fn(*call_item.args, **call_item.kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\yglazner\My Documents\LiClipse Workspace\anaconda_stuff\mproc.py", line 5, in wait_on_b
        print(b.result())
    NameError: name 'b' is not defined
    """
```